# How do I stop my trackpad leaving cursors all over my screen?

Tags: windows, gui, synaptics-touchpad, mouse-cursor

On my Windows laptop, when I double-finger scroll using the trackpad, a little icon pops up next to the mouse cursor, and when I stop scrolling, the icon usually disappears.

[image: Scroll icon]

Occasionally, the icon gets stuck on the screen, and sometimes I end up with several icons on the screen:

[image]

I can get rid of them by killing the Synaptics TouchPad 64-bit Enhancements process:

[image: kill Synaptics TouchPad 64-bit Enhancements process]

Is there some way to fix this minor annoyance?

Can I prevent the icons getting stuck?

Can I prevent the icon appearing in the first place?

Can I replace the icon with a completely transparent image, or one of zero size?

Can I automatically kill the Synaptics TouchPad 64-bit Enhancements process every few seconds?

Comment: Could you try to uninstall or reinstall the synaptics application and/or driver?

Comment: @mashuptwice - Thanks. I tried that but the problem persists.

Comment: You tried uninstalling and the issue persisted with the generic windows driver or you tried reinstalling? Did you try to install an updated version of the driver & utility?